# move one vertical line with mouse over and find intersection point with two highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have two line charts in a page. I am using highcharts for plotting charts.

I want to move one vertical line with mouse move and want to find out data points of each graph at which vertical line intersects graph.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <style>
  #reporting {
   position: absolute; 
   top: 55px; 
   right: 20px; 
    font: 12px Arial, Verdana; 
    color: #666;
   }
  </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var $reporting = $('#reporting');
            var $reporting1 = $('#reporting1');

            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                },
                xAxis: {
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                mouseOver: function() {
                                    $reporting.html('x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        events: {
                            mouseOut: function() {
                                $reporting.empty();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                    }]
            });

            //second chart
            $('#container1').highcharts({
                chart: {
                },
                xAxis: {
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                mouseOver: function() {
                                    $reporting1.html('x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        events: {
                            mouseOut: function() {
                                $reporting1.empty();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                        data: [9.9, 71.5, 16.4, 129.2, 144.0, 120.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 5.6, 4.4]
                    }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 300px; min-width: 300px"></div>
    <div id="reporting"></div>
    <div id="container1" style="height:300px;min-width:300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

what it does is reflecting x and y coordinate in html.

But on mouse move in one graph one vertical line should be drawn and it html should reflect intersection point of one vertical line with both graphs.

Comment: your fiddle isn't working, please fix.

Comment: it is working. but it is not working according to my requirement and i  did not find anything to make vertical line.

Comment: it not works at all. highchart isn't loaded.

GET http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js 403 (Forbidden)

**use cdn**

Comment: updated question and put my whole code there.

Comment: The problem, that highcharts applied captcha on their site, my isp is dynamic ip, so....

Comment: so X move should not to be fixed ? and you want to get interpolated results on crosss ?

Comment: X of vertical line should move with mouse move and it should move on both the charts and i want to find points of graph1 and graph2 at which vertical line intersects.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/tVCv9/14/ and want to find vertical moving line's intersection point with both line graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate this by using the crosshairs option, the shared tooltip option, and by plotting both lines on a single chart, with 2 different stacked x axes.

See this `example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/LHZ3E/5/

In my example, I have a fixed position tooltip that sits between the 2 charts, and I have added a click event to open a jquery ui dialog with a more detailed tooltip.  But you can just have a normal tooltip instead...

crosshairs options:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.crosshairs

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is not supported, however you can achieve that by adding mouse move event for chart, where you will get `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`. Now use [`axis.toValue()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toValue) to get value, and display that on a chart. To draw that line you can use plotLine and updating that line.